# How can i compare two arbitrary versions of same project in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Hi have recently configured SonarQube 5.1 and have added a dummy Java project.
After running the sonar-runner i'm able to see the difference between the current version and any other version which i want (using project variable "Period 4" and "Period 5"), but how can i see the difference between any two random versions. For example i ran the analysis on version 1, 2, 3 and 4 of the project and now i want to see the difference between version 1 and 2 or 2 and 3.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you resync the project to the specific version, then run the analysis? This would make a mess of the history a little, but if this a one off task you wish to do, it might be worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily compare the metrics, but not the issues, of versions using the More -> Compare option in the project menu. You land at a compare page pre-loaded with recent versions of the project. It is here that you can add/substitute your arbitrary versions.

For that matter, you can use this interface (also reachable through the global More -> Compare Projects) menu item to compare projects.

The page loads with a fixed set of metrics which is easily editable.

Here's an [example on Nemo](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/comparison/index?resource=org.codehaus.sonar:sonar)

Note that only issues present during the most recent analysis and those closed in the last 30 days are retained in the database, so it's not possible to compare issues from previous versions, only metrics.

Comment: Thank you for the info, but suppose i'm comparing version 2 and 4, now if i want to view the details of the issues that were not there in v2 but were introduced in v4, how can i achieve this?

Comment: ....additionally v4 is not the version on which current analysis ran, lets say we also have v7 for which current analysis ran.

Comment: @hyperion you can't compare individual issues from old versions, only metrics. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out the time machine and configuring custom timeline widgets. You can get a quick info on changes of specific metrics.
Check out the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: hi gautam, thanks for answering but this is not what i'm looking for. I want to view list of issues along with the details that were introduced between any two anonymous versions of an application.